# RAW images and PHP

Tags: php, image

I would like to extract a thumbnail from a RAW image file, like Canon's .CR2 or Nikon's .NEF. I've understood that this can somehow be done with ImageMagick, but haven't grasped if it's possible through the PHP wrapper.

Are there any good solutions? Preferably using the built in thumbnail for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, iMagick (the php version of ImageMagick) can handle these extensions: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

[Here's a great set of tuts](http://valokuva.org/) that got me going with Imagick.  The owner responded to a few of my questions quickly, and despite a bit of a language barrier was able to easily get me through my hurdles

As an aside, I've begun using [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) to do image admin. No need to worry about thumbnailing, uploading, etc....it's all automatic.  Then on the front end I can do jquery magic (getting photos via php query from the gallery database tables) to make it look really good.

Comment: Caution and addition: There's not a single RAW format, not even a single .CR2 or .NEF. Camera companies keep updating (and further obscuring) their RAWs with every model advance. Because's there's more recordable date and/or because they want their tools to lead. Which is an expensive cat and mouse, even for those big corporation who maintain tehir raw library. Hence be prepared, that the very latest camera bodies raw...

Comment: On another note: Most Raw-Formats formally (in terms of chunk structure...) look like TIFF. Hence just jumping to the pre-existing thumbnail might be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, if PHP's imagemagick libraries are to support this, they would be drawing from some functionality exposed through imagemagick's 'identify' command line tool (as the tool would be itself exposing functionality in the imagemagick libraries). Looking at the [documentation for this tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php), it doesn't look good. If you tried running identify -verbose, theoretically, the thumbnail information would appear in there somewhere, perhaps as an encoded value. Try it yourself: if it does, maybe you could possibly further extract the information returned from identify, either through the imagemagick functions in PHP (though I don't see any past the Exif libraries which only work on JPEG), or by scraping the return of a PHP system call to the identify tool.

Either way, doesn't look likely.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Horn has submitted a complete example about reading the requested data and even saving it locally for later use.

Check this out: 
https://benjaminhorn.io/code/extracting-thumbnails-from-camera-raw-files-cr2-and-nef-with-php/